# tpl dataflow maxdegreeofparalellism

Tags: c#, .net, concurrency, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I'm constructing a pipeline using TPL Dataflow. Say I have a pipeline that consists of four TransformBlocks

```
GetDataFromDatabase
ProcessData1
ProcessData2
SendDataToRestService
```

Each of these may (probably will) be a long running operation. GetDataFromDatabase will probably mostly be waiting for the database to respond, SendDataToRestService be waiting for the service to response. ProcessData 1 and 2 will be long running local, CPU intense processes.

Now, my intention was to set maxdegreeofparalellism on each of my blocks to the number of cores on the machine (which will probably be 4).

But it occurs to me that that means that it will do 4 GetDataFromDatabases at once, and 4 ProcessData1 at once, and 4 ProcessData2 at once, and 4 SendDataToRestService at once. Which would mean I could potentially have 16 threads running at the same time. Add to this that I actually have 3 different flows doing similar stuff at the same time.

QUESTION: What's the best approach to this, so that I get the best performance? From what I've read, if I try to do too much, I can actually slow down performance due to context switching. Is there a best approach, or is it "suck it and see"?

Comment: It seems to me that the latter 3 steps can be done in one `ActionBlock`. No pipeline necessary.

Comment: In fact I don't see why you'd need more than one `ActionBlock` at all. Just post all work items into it and use an async worker delegate. You can set the degree of parallelism that way.

Comment: You might be right, but, and forgive me if I'm missing something, but couldn't you say that about any pipeline? In which case, what's the point of them?

Comment: I'm kind of new to TPL dataflow but the value of linking blocks together seems to be in composing *different* kinds of blocks with different behaviors. If you just need a one-step pipeline, so be it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, as @usr suggested, your case fits a single `ActionBlock`. The point of linking multiple blocks is to compose different types of blocks with different configurations. For example if you had one step with `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of 1, and another with 10.

Second, `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` sets the maximum, which means that the `TPL` can choose any number in that range according to the availability of resources. So I wouldn't fear setting the maximum value for all those blocks, and if `TPL` decides it's better to use less threads, it will.

From [How to: Specify the Degree of Parallelism in a Dataflow Block](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh228609%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Because the MaxDegreeOfParallelism property represents the maximum degree of parallelism, the dataflow block might execute with a lesser degree of parallelism than you specify. The dataflow block can use a lesser degree of parallelism to meet its functional requirements or to account for a lack of available system resources. A dataflow block never chooses a greater degree of parallelism than you specify.

Comment: Hi. I'd already considered reducing the number of blocks I had, but wasn't sure I had a good reason. I liked the 'unit of work' aspect of it. However, I think I can see that in this case, it may not be the best thing to do, so I will simplify it. Having said that, I had simplified my scenario somewhat for the purpose of the question - perhaps I'd simplified it too much :-). I certainly have requirements for some of my blocks to process just one at a time, which is what they are currently doing. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @user1158174 sure, any time.

Answer (score 0):

I think what would make sense here would be to combine the two CPU-bound blocks into one. That way, you can tune the blocks with different characteristics separately.

If that wasn't possible (that could happen for example if the CPU-bound blocks weren't next to each other in the pipeline), then it would most likely still be okay to set `MaxDegreeOfParallelism` of each CPU-bound block to `ProcessorCount`. The thread pool is smart and won't use too many threads, unless it thinks it would be advantageous. Though I think using blocking IO code in the other blocks (or other parts of the program) could confuse this, so I would suggest using asynchronous IO.

In any case, using slightly more threads than necessary most likely won't be a big problem. If you really need to fix this anyway, you could use [a custom `TaskScheduler` that limits the number of threads](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pfxteam/archive/2010/04/09/9990424.aspx) and set that as the `DataflowBlockOptions.TaskScheduler` for the CPU-bound blocks.